# Самолистающие картинка на jQuery

Tags: jquery

```js
setInterval(function() {
    var currentImage = $('.slider-img.img-curry').index();
    var nextImageIndex = currentImage + 1;
    var nextImage = $('.slider-img').eq(nextImageIndex);
    nextImage.click();
  }, 800);
  $('.slider img').on('click', function() {
     $('.slider img').removeClass('img-curry');   // слайдер 
     $(this).addClass('img-curry');
     $('.slider-content').removeClass('slider-curry');   // слайдер 
     $(this).parent().addClass('slider-curry');
     
    
 
      
  });
```

```css
.slider img {
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-bottom: 75px;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0.5;
 
}
.slider-curry img {
  opacity: 1;
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slider">
<div class="slider-content slider-curry">
            <img class="slider-img img-curry" src="http://via.placeholder.com/130x130" alt="" width="130" height="130">
          
          </div>
           <div class="slider-content">
            <img class="slider-img" src="http://via.placeholder.com/130x130" alt="" width="130" height="130">
          
          </div>
           <div class="slider-content">
            <img class="slider-img" src="http://via.placeholder.com/130x130" alt="" width="130" height="130">
          
          </div>
          </div>
```

ПОчему выбирается всегда одно и тоже изображение? по идеии должно 1 2 3. Посмотрите пожалуйста код

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выбиралось оно потому что `currentImage` всегда возвращал 0, т.к. классы `.slider-img.img-curry` имеют индекс 0 внутри родителя `.slider-content`. Стоило брать индекс класса `.slider-curry` родителя `.slider`. Потом делаем проверку на последнее изображение, если последнее, то обнуляем `nextImageIndex`, иначе идем дальше и прибавляем 1. Затем удаляем/добавляем нужные классы.

Так же вынесем `setInterval` в отдельную функцию и присвоим глобальной переменной, потому что его придется останавливать при клике на изображение.

```js
var $repeat;
$(document).ready(function () {
    slide();
    $('.slider img').on('click', function() {
        clearInterval($repeat);
        $('.slider-img').removeClass('img-curry');
        $(this).addClass('img-curry');
        $('.slider-content').removeClass('slider-curry');
        $(this).parent().addClass('slider-curry');
        slide();
    });
});

function slide() {
    var content, currentImageIndex, nextImageIndex, nextImage;
    $repeat = setInterval(function() {
        currentImageIndex = $('.slider-curry').index();
        if (nextImageIndex === $('.slider').children().length - 1) {
            nextImageIndex = 0;
        }
        else {
            nextImageIndex = currentImageIndex + 1;
        }
        content = $('.slider-content');
        nextImage = content.eq(nextImageIndex).find('.slider-img');
        $('.slider-img').removeClass('img-curry');
        nextImage.addClass('img-curry');
        content.removeClass('slider-curry');
        nextImage.parent().addClass('slider-curry');
    }, 2000);
}
```

```css
.slider img {
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-bottom: 75px;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0.5;
 
}
.slider-curry img {
  opacity: 1;
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="slider">
    <div class="slider-content slider-curry">
        <img class="slider-img img-curry" src="http://via.placeholder.com/130x130" alt="" width="130" height="130">
    </div>
    <div class="slider-content">
        <img class="slider-img" src="http://via.placeholder.com/130x130" alt="" width="130" height="130">
    </div>
    <div class="slider-content">
        <img class="slider-img" src="http://via.placeholder.com/130x130" alt="" width="130" height="130">
    </div>
</div>
```